# Problem if population list with object created using Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#

I'm using the code below an I'm stuck at understand why I cant populate the list by an object created with `Activator.CreateInstance()`

```
var type = GetType("SmartAdmin.Models.Moddle");
var t = db.Moddles.ToList();

if (t.Count == 0)
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var prop in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.Name == "String")
        {
            prop.SetValue(instance, "1");
        }
        else
        {
            prop.SetValue(instance, 1);
        }

    }
    t.Add(instance);
}
```

When `t.Add(instance);` run it return no error and go the next line of code, but `t` is still empty.

Can someone explain why it's not working.

I know I could just create a new instance of `Moddle`, but I'm trying to learn so that why I wanted to try something different.

Comment: Have you made sure `t.Count == 0` is true? You're currently setting `t` to `db.Moddles.ToList()`, so is it possible that it is not empty, thus your code in that block is never executed?

Comment: You need to cast your instance to Moddle.  `var instance = (Moddle)Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

Comment: There's something you're not telling us here. Firstly this can't even compile so it cannot be your actual code. Secondly, what is the `GetType` method?

Comment: Code as shown produces error `Cannot convert from 'object' to 'Moddle'` at line `t.Add(...)`. You need to type-cast it, as already mentioned above: `t.Add((Moddle)instance)`. And then it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mgvhA3

Comment: @DavidG I don't know if he's using MVC, but if I run he's code in MVC, everything compiles just fine and run, and as he says, t.add(instance) runs but don't add the new object. But can confirm that (Moddle)instance works.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `t` is a typed list (I assume the results of an Entity Framework call, but that's speculation), it's not possible to add an item of type `object` to it, that won't compile. Whether it's MVC or not is not relevant.